# How to display Membership UserName from UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to accomplish a task of displaying review comments for an item.
In this view, I am using Kendo UI Grid:

**The View**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
    .Name("ReviewCommentsGrid")
    .Columns(
       columns =>
       {
          columns.Bound(rc => rc.UserId);
          columns.Bound(rc => rc.Comment);
          columns.Bound(rc => rc.CommentDate);
          columns.Bound(rc => rc.UpdateCommentDate);
          columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
       }
    )
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine);
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource(
        dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("UpdateCommentDate").Descending())
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add("CommentDate").Descending())
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(rc => rc.ReviewCommentId);
            model.Field(rc => rc.Comment).Editable(true);
            model.Field(rc => rc.UserId).Editable(false);
            model.Field(rc => rc.CommentDate).Editable(false);
            model.Field(rc => rc.UpdateCommentDate).Editable(false);
        })
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadReviewComments", "Controller"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateReviewComment", "Controller"))
    )
 )
```

**The Problem**
As seen here, I am using UserId in the 1st column. This is a Guid in my ASP.NET Membership table. However, instead of displaying as a Guid, I would like to display as an UserName. I cannot leave the cell to be a Guid.

I have tried to following variations:

```
columns.Bound(rc => Membership.GetUser(rc.UserId).UserName);
```

**Result**: A blank table cell

```
columns.Template(@<text>@Membership.GetUser(rc.UserId).UserName</text>);
```

**Result**: A blank table cell

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

**Edit**
I have decided to move away from the `Ajax` and `DataSource` binding. I started by binding the list of models to my parent ViewModel of the view (this list if populated in the controller).

**1)**Remove the DataSource binding from the Grid
**2)**Remove the `Command.Edit()` and replaced it with `Command.Custom()`, like so:

```
columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Custom("Update").Text("Update").Click("updateComment"));
```

**3)**Now since there is no Ajax, I can use server-side `Column.Template`
**4)**Now since I am able to bind with server-side:

```
columns.Template(@<text><span>@Membership.GetUser(item.UserId).UserName</span></text>).Title("User Name);
```

Thank you,
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the ClientTemplate with Ajax binding.

```
columns.Template(@<text></text>)
       .ClientTemplate(@<text>@Membership.GetUser(#= UserId #)
                                         .UserName</text>);
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#clienttemplate

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a compilation error. `CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`. I have been searching for alteratives. I used `item` instead of `rc` and it turns out to be a nullable parameter, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Try the hash syntax. See edited answer. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

Comment: I have tried that. It's like using client side with server side methods. It's not possible because the server renders before client.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'll mark this as answered, but I did go down a different route to accomplish my task.

Comment: I wondered about the membership call. I use Identity so when I want to display the user name I just pull it from the AspNetUsers table and include it in the bound viewmodel.

Comment: I also pull from the AspNetUsers table, but I only bring the Guid. I could make another property for the UserName, but I decided against it. Right now, it's working with my custom Ajax. Thank you again.